# Read updates from continuously updated directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script that looks at each file in a directory and does some sort of action to it. It's supposed to look something like this (maybe?).

```
for file in "$dir"* ; do
    something
done
```

Cool, right? The problem is, this directory is being updated frequently (with new files). There is no guarantee that, at some point, I will *technically* be done with all the files in the dir (therefore exiting the for-loop), but not actually done feeding the directory with extra files. There is no guarantee that I will *never* be done feeding the directory (well... take that with a grain of salt).

I do NOT want to process the same file more than once.

I was thinking of making a while loop that runs forever and keeps updating some file-list A, while making another file-list B that keeps track of all the files I already processed, and the first file in file-list A that is not in file-list B gets processed.

Is there a better method? Does this method even work? Thanks

Edit: Mandatory "I am bash newb"

Comment: Maybe use `inotify` to get notified when new files are added?

Comment: *I do NOT want to process the same file more than once.* Then don't use bash to process files based on their location in an ever-changing directory.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what is your suggestion then..?

Comment: First, you have to solve the problem of knowing the entire file is there, and it's contents are correct.  And doing that *requires* cooperation of the process creating the files - only that process has the information needed to know if the file has been completely and correctly written.  The usual way to do that is to have the sender create some sort of empty "flag" file, or to use a rename or move operation to indicate the file is complete.  Then, when you start processing it, you move or rename the file.  IMO it's best to use move operations and put files into single-purpose directories.

Comment: That works as long as your OS supports atomic move and rename operations, that works without problems.  For example: files are uploaded to an "/some/path/inprogress" directory, then the sender moves the file to "/some/path/upload".  If it's in the "upload" directory, you haven't processed it yet.  Once you process it, you can move it to a "/some/path/done" directory.  That's all state-driven, and if it crashed in the middle, you'll only reprocess files that you weren't already done with.

Answer (score 2):

@Barmar has a good suggestion.  One way to handle this is using `inotify` to watch for new files.  After installing the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) on your system, you can use the `inotifywait` command to feed new-file events into a loop.

You may start with something like:

```
inotifywait -m -e MOVED_TO,CLOSED_WRITE myfolder |
while read dir events file, do
  echo "Processing file $file"
  ...do something with $dir/$file...
  mv $dir/$file /some/place/for/processed/files
done
```

This `inotifywait` command will generate events for (a) files that are moved into the directory and (b) files that are closed after being opened for writing.  This will generally get you what you want, but there are always corner cases that depend on your particular application.

The output of `inotifywait` looks something like:

```
tmp/work/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE file1
tmp/work/ MOVED_TO file2
```

Comment: This works, but those corner cases you mention aren't really all that rare, especially for busy systems.  There's also no indication that the entire file is there.  The main problem I have with using something like `inotify` for this?  It's *event-driven*.  Events can be lost, or not identified at all.  If a file is uploaded or created when `inotifywait` isn't running, that file won't be processed. In my experience, purely state-based solutions are much more reliable.